# Magento 2 add "Tel:" in address-renderer

Tags: magento2

How can I add "Tel:" before `<!-- ko if: (address().telephone) -->`  in default.phtml.
When the customer does not provide a phone number, "Tel" will be not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
<a if="address().telephone" attr="'href': 'tel:' + address().telephone" text="address().telephone"></a>
```

Comment: It does not work